# Obtain value of SharePoint Lookup column from getJSON query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint, getjson

I am using getJSON to retrieve data from a SharePoint list svc.  I would like to obtain the value of a Lookup column.  It currently returns an [object object] response.  Is there some way to get the actual value?  Have posted this on MSDN but Microsoft does not know how to do it.  If someone has done it, i will update my post on MSDN to tell Microsoft how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[object Object] is just a generic way of telling you that you're trying to output an object as a string.

You can treat the object like an array, and iterate through the keys to find all the values.

```
for (var key in objectVar) {
   console.log("key: " + key + "\nvalue: " + objectVar[key]);
}
```

You may have to get recursive in order to get the values of objects in objects.

If you use Fiddler, you can dissect the response itself. If you use Chrome, you can just dump the entire object to console and it will show you the whole thing.

You can also add a breakpoint in IE debugger tools, then set a watch on the variable, and expand the variable in the watch area.

Be warned, sharepoint lookup field values need to be split on the # usually.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  key returns _deferred and objectVar[key] returns [object object].
Here is my code: 
var myParent = data.d.results[i].Parent;
    for (var key in myParent) {
     console.log("key: " + key + "\nvalue: " + myParent[key]);
    }

Also, debugging in IE9 just locks my screen.

Comment: Have you considered using SPServices? It makes accessing this type of data significantly easier.

Comment: I have.  We use NewsGator which uses jquery 1.9.1.  This does not support SPServices.

Comment: ouch. well can you try another browser? firefox and chrome are better at handling browser debugging.

Comment: I am not permitted to use Chrome and Firefox doesn't support SharePoint.  I'm in a real jam here.